# wscat established connection with k8s pod container, but command interaction with it fails

Tags: kubernetes

I use wscat having successfully established connection with pod container(/bin/bash), but when I send command to it, I received no response from it. Could anyone tell me why?
[image]

Comment: I got the reason now. K8S api-server using websocket sub-protocol to exchange data. For input(stdin), the protocol requires the payload is heading with '\0' byte, not zero, it's ascii zero-valued character. So wscat is limited to interacting with k8s pod due to wscat can not send invisible character.

Comment: Could you post it as an answer so others can benefit from it?

Answer (score 1):

Posting @user3398604 solution as community wiki for better visibility:

> K8S api-server using websocket sub-protocol to exchange data. For
>   input(stdin), the protocol requires the payload is heading with '\0'
>   byte, not zero, it's ascii zero-valued character. So wscat is limited
>   to interacting with k8s pod due to wscat can not send invisible
>   character.